Doubt about cubic polynomial factorization?
I have seen a problem in polynomial factorization in Litvinenko/Mordkovitch's book. The problem asks to factor $a^3-7a^2+7a+15$.
The solution given there is as follows:

It is not clear to me how the Authors guessed the rewriting for $-7a^2$ and $7a$. I tried to make something in the same spirit and I wrote:
$$X(x-r)+Y(x-r)+Z(x-r)$$
Here I must have $X=x^2,Y=\alpha x, Z=\beta$. Expanding and collecting for $x$ I get:
$$x^3+x^2 (\alpha -r)+x (\beta -\alpha  r)-\beta  r$$
Comparing coefficients with the initial polynomial, I get the following system:
$$-\beta  r=15\\ \beta -\alpha  r=7 \\ \alpha -r=-7$$
But this just seemed to make the problem harder. Also: How general is this? Should I expect it to work with any polynomial of degree 3?

Not all polynomials of degree three have integer roots. Some need cube roots of complex numbers (if they have 3 distinct real roots).

It doesn't make the problem harder---it's the same as the original if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are eliminated. To me, I'd just first check $\pm$factors of $15$ to see if anyone works, by rational root theorem. The author's choice of $3$ is not unique and one may choose $-1$ or $5$.

@Lucenaposition Yeah, I noticed that this polynomial behaves well. I was thinking if doing such a thing would happen when they don't behave well.

@ZackFisher Yeah, I know about the rational root theorem. But I thought that they were doing this without knowing anything about the roots.

Then, it's probably just experience and luck.

When the Question gets made by somebody & the Answer gets given by somebody else , then "luck" might get involved , @ZackFisher , though here there was no "luck" involved because the Question was generated with the Answer already "known" to those Authors.

The Authors are high-lighting various ways/methods/tips/techniques to factorize.
"When factoring polynomials, we use various methods: taking out of the brackets a common factor, grouping, making use of the formulas for short-cut multiplication, and so on. Consider several examples to illustrate these methods."
Illustrative Examples are then given there.
When one way does not work out , other methods must be tried.

Eg We want to factorize $x^4+39x^2+380$
(1) We can write $39x^2=19x^2+20x^2$ & $380=19 \times 20$
We can then factorize in terms of $x^2$.
(2) We require two numbers which Sum up to $39$ , while keeping the Product $380$ : We might guess at $\sqrt{380} \approx \sqrt{400}$ & try with $ 20 - 1 , 20 , 20 + 1$
(3) We can try this third alternative : Solve the Quadratic Equation with $y=x^2$ & get the roots $19,20$ , which will give the factorization.
Eventually we will get $(x^2+19)(x^2+20)$
How did I know to use $19,20$ ? Well , I made the Exercise , hence I knew what I wanted !

In your Case too , the Authors knew what was wanted & hence zeroed-in on that.
In other words , the Authors took $(x+1)(x-3)(x+5)$ & expanded it to make that Exercise.
The first factor we can get might as well be $(x+5)$ , instead of $(x-3)$
It is only to high-light that method.
The Crux is to observe & try with suitable numbers. When it works , great. Else try next technique.

The Authors have given Examples where there is no further factorization : You should try the techniques there to verify that.
There are around 40 Exercises where you can use those techniques to get Experience , to know which will work where & which will not work where.

Ah, I thought they were doing that without knowing any of the roots beforehand. This changes things a bit.
